# command git submodule foreach 'git tag -l | echo "HELLO"' always echo HELLO

Tags: bash

I'm on a wsl Ubuntu 20.04 and cannot comprehend why my command does not seem to take into account my first parameter as if it has trouble interpreting the quotes. Any idea on what is going on here?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The `|` ("pipe") sends output from the first command to the input of the second command, but `echo "HELLO"` doesn't read its input, it just prints "HELLO". What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response i expect it to do the first command but if not prints HELLO instead. This is not the real command i'm trying to use this is just an example but really i'm trying to delete specific tags and if there are no tags prints skip in the same way my exemple does

Comment: Do you want `||` ("or") instead of `|` (pipe)? That'll run the second command only if the first command exits with a failure/error status. (Although it's often better to use `if ! command1; then command2; fi`) See ["Lists of Commands" in the bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists).

Comment: The thing is because of the foreach i think that even if the first statement is true it won't give me the prompt back as i would enter in an "infinite loop" right?

Comment: `foreach` isn't a valid command in bash; are you using csh or tcsh instead? Please edit your question to include the exact command you're using (use [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and make sure it renders correctly), what it does, and what you expect/want it to do.

Comment: i'm using the command git submodule foreach 'git tag -d folder/version3 | echo "SKIPPED" ' i want this command to go through the submodules of my git repository and delete a specific release version if there is one, if not print skipped

Comment: @Christophe : that's `||` instead of `|` (as said by GordonDavisson)

Comment: @LeGEC the problem is i have multiple submodule so i'm not sure if i put the OR operator that my loop would stop once it found one version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, `|` is a pipe, so any output of `git tag -l` is piped to `echo` and because `echo` does not really read the input, just ignores it, all you get is "HELLO".

The OR operator, `||`, is probably what you want, although it won't work just like that with `git tag -l`, because that command returns success even if there are no tags. But in the comments you mention that what you actually want is `git tag -d TAG`. That should work fine, because it returns failure when TAG does not exist.

You also worry that using OR operator would prematurely stop processing your modules. The opposite is actually true. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):

> A non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding || : to the end of the command.

So without `||` the processing will stop on the first submodule, which doesn't have TAG.

In case you want it to work with `git tag -l` too, you have to somehow make it return failure if there are no tags. One way, maybe not the best, is pipe its output to `grep ".*"`. Some example:

```sh
]$ git submodule foreach 'git tag -l "v5.0*beta1" | grep ".*" || echo "NOT FOUND"'
Entering 'qtactiveqt'
v5.0.0-beta1
Entering 'qtbase'
NOT FOUND
Entering 'qtqa'
v5.0.0-beta1
Entering 'qtrepotools'
v5.0.0-beta1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. I think i'm going to follow you all advices and use the OR operator instead of the pipe one. git submodule foreach 'git tag -d folder/version3 || echo "SKIPPED" '